# Matrix multiplication of $A^k=A×A×\cdots×A$

Tags: analysis, matrices

$A = (a_{ij})∈K^{n×n}\ $ with:

$$a_{ij}=\left\{\begin{array}{cl} 1, & \mbox{if }j =i +1\\ 0, & \mbox{if }j≠ i + 1  \end{array}\right.$$

I need to calculate the matrix product for every $k∈ℕ$:
$$A^k=A×A×\cdots×A$$

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this. All the definitions we have do not all help me at all. I want to understand how this works, as I think that this will be the kind of problem that's asked in the finals (this is from an older test). Both, solution and hints would help me a lot here.

Comment: "All the definitions do not help"? How about the definition of matrix multiplication, that seems likely to be useful.

Comment: Take a $\,3\times 3\;\;or\;\;4\times 4\;$ matrix $\;A\;$ as defined by you, and calculate $\,A^2\,,\,A^3\;$ , say. I bet you will see a rather interesting pattern and hopefully this will take you to the general case...

Answer (score 8):

Try some examples; $n=2$ and $n=3$ might be too small to give you a good idea of what’s going on, but $n=4$ is useful.

$$A^2=\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\;,
$$

and

$$A^3=\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0
\end{bmatrix}\;;$$

I’ll let you calculate $A^4$, guess the pattern, and prove it by induction.